# Stationary poisson distribution, given probability of subset

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

so given that the probability of a customer entering a store is between 50 and 70 years old is 5/9. 
What is the probability that the 7th customer entering the store is also the 3rd customer who is between 50 and 70?
Then, with 7 people in the store, what is the probability that 3 of them are between 50 and 70 years old?

I'm having trouble figuring out how to approach these - I thought about setting the two Poisson distributions equal, but that didn't get me anywhere. I'm wondering if it requires a conditional probability.

Comment: Let $\lambda$ be the mean rate of customers entering the store (which for some reason is unspecified, why? You need a rate parameter to use a Poisson process). Let $p=5/9$ the proportion of customers who are in age range $[50,70]$. Then the number of customers arriving who are in that age range is a new Poisson process with rate $\lambda p$. The second item you seek is $P(N=3|X=7)$, where $X$ is the original process with rate $\lambda$ and $N$ is the new process with rate $\lambda p$.

Comment: Lambda unfortunately was not provided. I was just having a problem figuring out what conditional probability was needed to answer the problem. Thanks